# Could not find a valid gem 'prawn_report' in Rails 2 app deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, prawn

I have this problem below on old Rails app deploy:

> [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in
> the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you
> can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
>
> gem install prawn_report ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem
> 'prawn_report' (>= 0) in any repository ERROR:  Possible alternatives:
> rake_report, ar_report, amazon_report, app_report, plain_record

Any suggestions to solve this problem are welcome.

Comment: only this kind of prawn gem are available.(https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=prawn)

Comment: Now: https://rubygems.org/gems/prawn_report

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prawn report isn't in the https://rubygems.org you can't install in this way.